# Python parsing url into dict: duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a raw text data file consisting of ids and urls. I would then like to parse the urls into Python dictionaries and then transformed into pandas dataframes, so that I can analyse certain url elements.

The issue is that some of elements are duplicates. For example, a url may read `/browse/?item_type=15&color=336&color=45`. Note `color=` shows up twice. Then if I use urllib.parse.parse_qs to parse the url, the resulting dictionary would contain the key value pair 'color' - ['336','45'], the value being a list. As a consequence, an error is thrown when I try to concatenate the parsed line into the existing dataframe of url elements:

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

```
new_df = DataFrame.from_dict(urllib.parse.parse_qs(df1['url'][1]), orient='columns', dtype=None)
new_df['id'] = df1['id'][1]
for i in range(2,35):
    add_df = DataFrame.from_dict(urllib.parse.parse_qs(df1['url'][i]), orient='columns', dtype=None)
    add_df['id'] = df1['id'][i]
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, add_df])
```

My question is: how do I bypass this issue? At this point, I'm willing to accept just one color into my dataframe if there are two colors -- the cases where the url contains two colors are few.

Comment: Rather than passing the dict returned by `parse_qs` directly to `DataFrame.from_dict` just do a little preprocessing step to search for keys that have list values and replace them with, say, the first value in the list.  Or some other scheme if you do want to keep multiple colors.

Comment: You could also transform lists into tuples, e.g. `tuple(['336','45'])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{k: [v[0]] for k, v in parse_qs('item_type=15&color=336&color=45').items()}
```

This will eliminate any duplicates